# How to use Mockito in the AndroidTest source set

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

How do you use Mocks in an Integration test(AndroidTest). I'm receiving the following error.

```
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
```

I'm using the following dependencies.

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.11.2" <br>
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2" <br>
```

I don't think dexmaker is required anymore.

```
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.1"
```

I've excluded the following classes because the build was complaining about multiple file paths.

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker"
    }
```

My Fragment test looks like this

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DetailsFragmentTest {


//    @get:Rule
//    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    private lateinit var  bundle: Bundle
    private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<DetailsFragment>


    @Mock
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {

        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)

        bundle = DetailsFragmentArgs("Test").toBundle()

        scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(
            factory = MainFragmentFactory(viewModel),
            fragmentArgs = bundle,
            themeResId = R.style.Theme_Words
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun textView_WordDescription() {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.tv_word))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
    }
    
}
```

I've tried initializing Mockito three different ways (they are ll commented out in the code above).

1. MockitoAnnotations.openMock(this)
2. @get:Rule
   val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJunit.rule()
3. @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)`

Is caused by an incompatible version of `ByteBuddy`. You can check the version of `ByteBuddy` you are using by finding it in the External Libraries and comparing it to the version `mockito-android` is using, you can check the version [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-android)

You will either need to change the `mockito-android` library to a version that matches the `ByteBuddy` version in your app or adjust the `ByteBuddy` to match the version in `mockito-android`